# Which technology is suitable for building scalable websites?

Tags: java, php, apache, web-applications

I want to know which technology is most appropriate for developing efficient websites which can be easily scaled in future?
By technology I mean, which:

Language: Java/Jsp ; PHP ; or a Ruby and Rails etc.
Server: Apache etc.
OS
DataBase
etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for Apache web server along with Mysql database which provide lot of scalability along with flexibility in Linux. And coming to programming language, PHP will be more efficient to use with Apache and Mysql. Recently many developers have opted Ruby and Rails also. But it is up to you to select the most comfortable language.